# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, gatsby

I have a gatsby app that used google maps api. I am loading both useRef and useEffect to load the map. useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import MapMarker from "../assets/images/logos/map-marker.png"

const Map = () => {
    
 const map = useRef(null)

  useEffect(()=>{

    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
      window.initMap = function() {
   const map = new window.google.maps.Map(map.current, {
        center: {
            lat: 142.1463554,
            lng: 121.5245996
        },
        zoom: 10,
        styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#d3d3d3"},{"lightness":50}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":50},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#4c4c4c"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#4c4c4c"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
      })

      new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 112.1463554, lng: 130.5245993 },
        icon: MapMarker,
        animation: window.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        map: map
    });
      }

    }

    return () => map.current = null

  }, [])
  


  return (
    <div id="map-container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12 col-12 pl-0 pr-0">
                    <div className="google-map">
                        <div id="map" ref={map}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```

When I loaded my gatsby app, it returned:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'current' of undefined
window.initMap
C:/Users/Read/Desktop/gatsby/src/components/Map.js:12
   9 | 
  10 |    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
  11 |      window.initMap = function() {
> 12 |   const map = new window.google.maps.Map(map.current, {
  13 |        center: {
  14 |            lat: 11.1463554,
  15 |            lng: 110.5245996
```

Any idea how to fix this? Please help!

Comment: `const map = new window.google.maps.Map(map.current` - surprised the error isn't about temporal dead zone ... since you're trying to use `map.current` before `map` is defined

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain? How do i fix it?

Comment: map is not defined until that constructor completes - so passing `map.current` won't work, since ... well ... map is not defined ... not sure how you fix it ... what are you trying to pass to that constructor? I guess you could try `const mapX = useRef(null)` earlier in the code, then use `mapX.current` - then try to understand variable scope

Comment: The error message is odd though ... which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: your code should produce `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'map' before initialization` error - how weird that you get a different error

Comment: I upvoted your answer yesterday but there is an eror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have naming issues when accessing the reference, since your `map` and your reference has the same name, it leads to this issue because of the scope. Change it to:

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react"
    import MapMarker from "../assets/images/logos/map-marker.png"
    
    const Map = () => {
        
     const mapRef = useRef(null)
    
      useEffect(()=>{
    
        if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
          window.initMap = function() {
       const map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, {
            center: {
                lat: 11.1463554,
                lng: 110.5245996
            },
            zoom: 10,
            styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#d3d3d3"},{"lightness":50}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":50},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#4c4c4c"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#4c4c4c"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
          })
    
          new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 112.1463554, lng: 130.5245993 },
            icon: MapMarker,
            animation: window.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            map: map
        });
          }
    
        }
    
        return () => mapRef.current = null
    
      }, [])

  


  return (
    <div id="map-container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12 col-12 pl-0 pr-0">
                    <div className="google-map">
                        <div id="map" ref={mapRef}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```